# Search Engine Ranking for this site is goofy

Tags: discussion

The first result on Google for [this search](https://www.google.com/webhp?rlz=1C1CHKZ_enUS432US432&sourceid=chrome-instant&ix=sea&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#hl=en&gs_nf=1&tok=C5lBdnwnE37wtRPGicdF6Q&cp=4&gs_id=k&xhr=t&q=stackexchange%20database%20admin&pq=sql%20server%20database%20replication&pf=p&rlz=1C1CHKZ_enUS432US432&sclient=psy-ab&pbx=1&oq=stac&aq=0p&aqi=p-p1g2g-z1&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&gs_l=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=2662c7bf2252b838&ix=sea&ion=1&biw=1920&bih=1033) still goes to the Area 51 site. That's not good, right?

Perhaps it's time to setup some 301's on the Area 51?

Comment: eh, if you setup 301's, how are you gonna get there to see the stats etc?

Comment: I'd move launched sites to a new subfolder that can then be indexed anew. Just pointing this out, as I found it very odd that the area 51 (completely worthless to 98% of people looking for DBA Q&A) came up first.

Comment: The Area 51 page has a bit "Visit this site now!" link, so it's not all bad.

Comment: So, you want all google traffic on those keywords to have to go through a different site to get here? that's really weird. If this is the site that is being promoted, this seems counter productive.